# intersection and union of polygons

Tags: math, matlab, geometry

I have polygons defined with their vertices's, and i need to calculate areas of their union and intersection. The most upsetting thing is that it is implemented in Mapping Toolbox, but i can't buy it. Does anyone knows how to make a fast algorithm to calculate it?
Thank you for your time.

Comment: The function is 'polybool'. And i can calculate the area with 'polyarea' (which is available for me).

Comment: I think you shouldn't ask for users to violate copyrights. Edited.

Comment: @Kate: Are your polygons guaranteed to be convex?

Comment: @Verde, amused as I was by your comment, I think your objection is misplaced. I think it's unlikely that the *algorithm* is belongs to MathWorks rather than the implementation, and the question is asking for an algorithm. Whether the (independent) re-implementation violates copyright or patent law, I suspect, depends on your jurisdiction.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found intersection points of my polygons and added vertices that are inside/outside polygons for intersection/union task (check if any of vertices of polygon 1 lies inside a polygon 2 and vice versa using 'inpolygon'). Then all points were transformed into polar coordinates with center in the mean coordinates of the matrix and sorted by angle, so that now they form consecutive closed contour. Knowing this it is easy to find intersection/union area using 'polyarea'.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to find the area of intersection ; the area of the union is trivially obtained from that. The [PolygonIntersection](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/18173-polygonintersection) package from FEX might be useful.

[image]

Comment: Can you show some pseudocode so that we can implement this in other languages as well?

Answer (score 1):

I would do like this:

1. Let *S* be the set of vertices from both polygons.
2. For each edge *e*<sub>1</sub> in polygon 1

   1. For each edge *e*<sub>2</sub> in polygon 2

      1. If *e*<sub>1</sub> intersects with *e*<sub>2</sub>

         1. Add the intersection point to *S*
3. Remove all vertices in *S* that are inside polygon 1 or 2.

The resulting set of vertices should make up the union of the polygons.

For the intersection you simply remove all vertices in *S* that are *outside* of both polygon 1 and 2 (in the third step).

(You can look up point intersection and "inside-polygon"-checks elsewhere ;-)

- [Intersection point of two lines](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/lineline2d/)
- [Determining if a point lies on the interior of a polygon](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/insidepoly/)

Comment: thank you for your answer, but how can i find intersection points? is it necessary to use equation of a line?

Comment: Added two links to my answer.

Comment: thank you. i know math, but unfortunately i'm not a very good programmer, so having codes there is very nice.

Comment: This FEX package computes the intersection points between polygons: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8908-curve-intersect-2.

Answer (score -1):

The idea is to break every intersect edge into four parts and form a new polygon with these. When you want the union, take the two outer edges. If you want intersection, take the two inner edges.

Comment: A great answer would give an example.