# Plotting intersection of planar surfaces in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I am looking to plot the intersection of two surfaces(patches) lying the same plane in MATLAB.[image]

As you can see in the above picture the green circle intersects four red rectangles.I want to plot out(or patch) only the four intersections.How do I proceed?

I tried to plot points on the circular patch which lies outside the intersection of one rectangle and circle using conditional statements.But MATLAB throws an error.Here is the code snippet.

```
[p,q] = size(points);
for s=1:1:q;
t = points(1,s);
if (points(1,s) >= Pa3(1,1)) && (points(1,s) <= Pa2(1,1)) && (points(2,s) >= Pa3(1,2)) &&  (points(2,s) <= Pa4(1,2))
    points(1,s) = 0;points(2,s) = 0;
end
end

fill3(points(1,:), points(2,:), points(3,:), 'g');
```

The above code throws an error at if statement.Basically in the code "points" represent all the points in the green circle.Pa1,Pa2,Pa3,Pa4 represent the vertices of the left top corner rectangle with Pa1 being the left corner top vertex and Pa2,Pa3,Pa4 following in clockwise manner.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Patches are defined by polygons, and what you are looking for is the intersection of two polygons which itself is a polygon.

If you have the *Mapping Toolbox*, you can use [polybool](http://www.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/polybool.html) to compute the intersection and other logical operations on polygons.

If not, have a look at the submission [Polygon_Intersection](http://www.mathworks.de/matlabcentral/fileexchange/18173-polygonintersection) on the Matlab File Exchange.

See also [intersection and union of polygons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7915734/intersection-and-union-of-polygons).