# Extracting all points within a patch

Tags: matlab, plot

I have an irregularly shaped patch between 4 points in space. How do extract information of all the points on the surface of the patch? I am asking this so as to perform intersection operations between two irregular shaped patches.

Comment: You mean [polygons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon), right?

Comment: Do the polygons you want to intersect lie in the same plane? If so, the output will be nothing, a point, or a polygon. If not, the output will be nothing, a point, or a line segment.

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272179/a-simple-algorithm-for-polygon-intersection).

Comment: Ya the polygons lie in the same plane.But in order to use the polybool function in MATLAB it needs all points on the two surfaces.Hence I wanted to convert the patch between 4 points to a surface with points on the patch surface.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7915734/intersection-and-union-of-polygons) might also be useful.

Comment: I finally got it.Using polybool function with patch only works.Thanks